# Return position of an item in ArrayList

Tags: java

I know that I can iterate the list and prove every element of the list. But I was wondering if there is better solution to get the position of an item in an ArrayList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) API offers you the [`indexOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method for that so that you don't need to manually iterate.

```
int index = list.indexOf(item);
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) - [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) - [List interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Comment: N.B. (@OP) this is typically implemented with iteration.